# How can we programmatically get call hierarchy for methods in IntelliJ

Tags: java, parsing, intellij-idea, call-hierarchy

Getting call hierarchy is easy in IntelliJ. Simply use the built in tool. But is there a way to do it using code? Eclipse internal JDT has two classes called CallHierarchy and MethodWrapper that help to do so: [link](https://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/find-all-callers-of-a-method/)

If there is no equivalent in IntelliJ, is there another pre-built way I can find all callers of a specific method (and base methods)? (Can we programmatically invoke `Find Usages`?)

In short, for a specific method, I'd like to get all other methods and classes that use the base method in a Collection<> of some sort.

Thanks in advance for any responses or ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. After research and a bunch of asking around, the IntelliJ developers pointed me at the IntelliJ Platform SDK... Didn't know this existed. [This link in particular points out how to use `Find Usages` in the SDK](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/find_usages.html). Hope this helps someone in the future.